# Проблема с Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. .NET Core (3.1)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-core

Помогите разобраться с проблемой: пишу на .NET Core(3.1) и нужно поработать(запись) с .xlsx. Почитал, что используют пакет Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - установил. Даже перед дебагом заметил предупреждение, что он может быть не до конца совместим с текущей платформой. Окей.

Ошибка вылетает следующего характера:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Не удается найти указанный файл.`

Гуглил: пишут, что может не совпадать версия excel (у меня 19 стоит), но чтобы не переставлять весь пакет office, решил спросить здесь, может проблема кроется не только в этом или вовсе и не в этом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так полагаю он не совместим с .NET Core, но вот в этой статье(в самом конце) сделали какой то велосипед, посмотрите ) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3a5cfda5-506b-46f8-94d3-f3af73a4ec49/problem-referencing-office-interop-from-net-core-3-preview-6?forum=netfxbcl

Вам принципиально не подходит .NET Framework ?

И кстати тут тоже вроде решали https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130446/net-core-3-0-and-ms-office-interop

Ну в общем ответы есть, надо только искать

Comment: На самом деле нет. Но уже написано достаточно кода... Я же не могу изменить целевую платформу в этом случае уже?

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP по обеим ссылкам вполне вменяемые решения. Вам нет нужды менять целевую платформу.

Comment: @aepot, сделал либу для работы с excel(framework), попытался запустить приложение и получил вот такую ошибку: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Библиотека не зарегистрирована. (0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))."

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP я не знаю ответа, но вы можете отредактировать вопрос и добавить туда эту информацию.

Comment: @aepot, добавлю лучше новый вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло добавить ссылку на модель COM:

[image: Обозреватель решений]